# Dynamically generating html form in ASP.Net MVC and C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razorengine

I have a class like this

```
public class Sample_Class {
    public string Property1 { get; set;}
    public string Property2 { get; set;}
}
```

and I want to have a html form like this:

```
<fieldset>
<legend>Change Password Form</legend>
    <ol>
        <li>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Property1)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Property1)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Property1)
        </li>
        <li>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Property2)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Property1)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Property1)
        </li>
    </ol>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</fieldset>
```

how can I do this dynamically? for example, like this:

```
....
    @foreach (property in Sample_Object.Properties) {
        <li>
            @Html.LabelFor(property)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(property)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(property)
        </li>
    }
....
```

Comment: You can use `foreach` such is shown in your above example. Are you wanting to create a partial-view instead?

Comment: @SamuelDavidson I prefer to have a partial-view, that get an Object and dynamically generate html form, based on Object's properties.

Comment: You don't have a `collection` property in your class. What it it that you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built-in [*`EditorForModel`*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.editorextensions.editorformodel.aspx) function:

```
@model Sample_Class


@Html.EditorForModel()
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

It essentially does what you want which is (according to the documentation)...

> [Return] an HTML input element for each property in the model.

The downside of `EditorForModel` is that you lose fine-grained control over your markup. That being said, you can customize the output to a certain extent using model attributes and the various overloads.